# How to disabled a button using Node.js and Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, button, handlebars.js, blogs

This is for a Node.js blog project.

I have a blog. I know how to create a new post. This post has a date of deadline. And every post has an 'Apply' button. I would like the project to disable the Apply button after the deadline.

This is my approach:

1. Create a post schema with the date to apply.
2. Create a logic using the routes.
3. Use it in handlebars.
   I tried but does not work.

This is the schema:

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose');
const UrlSlugs = require('mongoose-url-slugs');

const PostSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'categories'
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    slug: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'public'
    },
    allowComments: {
        type: Boolean,
        require: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    file: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    dateToApply: {
        type: Date
    },
    comments: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'comments'
    }]
}, {usePushEach: true});

PostSchema.plugin(UrlSlugs('title', {field: 'slug'}));

try {
    module.exports = model('posts', PostSchema);
} catch (e) {
    module.exports = model('posts');
}
```

This is the route:

```
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    const perPage = 10;
    const page = req.query.page || 1;

    let dateNow = Date.now();
    let applyDate = req.body.dateToApply;
    let button = document.getElementById('applyButton');

    function showButton() {
        if (dateNow > applyDate) {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
    

    Post.find({})
        .sort({date: 'desc'})
        .skip((perPage*page)-perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .then(posts => {
            Post.count().then(postCount=>{
                Category.find({}).then(categories => {
                    res.render('home/index', {
                        posts: posts,
                        categories: categories,
                        current: parseInt(page),
                        pages: Math.ceil(postCount/perPage)
                    });
                });
            });
        });
});
```

This is the Handlebars:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Home page</h1>
        {{#each posts}}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="/uploads/{{ file }}" alt="Kep">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">{{title}}</h2>
                <p class="card-text">{{body}}</p>
                <p>{{generateDate dateToApply 'MMMM DD YYYY'}}</p>
                <a href="/post/{{id}}" class="btn btn-primary">More</a>
                {{#if showButton}}
                <button id="applyBtn" class="btn btn-info">Apply</button>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                Date of post {{ generateDate date 'MMMM DD YYYY'}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {{#pagination current=current pages=pages}}{{/pagination}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add {{#if deadlinePass}} disabled {{/if}} to the button in handlesbars. You can't access the dom from the server.

Comment: Ok, but where is the logic? How can I tell the app that I need to disable the button after the deadline is passed if it is not in the server?

Comment: When you do then(posts => {, go over all the posts in foreach and calculated for each one if the deadline passed, and set it in post.deadlinePassed. then, when you pass the posts to handlebars, they will have this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    const perPage = 10;
    const page = req.query.page || 1;

    let dateNow = Date.now();
    
    Post.find({})
        .sort({date: 'desc'})
        .skip((perPage*page)-perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .then(posts => {
            posts.forEach(post => {
                post.deadlinePassed = dateNow > post.dateToApply
            })
            Post.count().then(postCount=>{
                Category.find({}).then(categories => {
                    res.render('home/index', {
                        posts: posts,
                        categories: categories,
                        current: parseInt(page),
                        pages: Math.ceil(postCount/perPage)
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Home page</h1>
        {{#each posts}}
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="/uploads/{{ file }}" alt="Kep">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">{{title}}</h2>
                <p class="card-text">{{body}}</p>
                <p>{{generateDate dateToApply 'MMMM DD YYYY'}}</p>
                <a href="/post/{{id}}" class="btn btn-primary">More</a>
                {{#if showButton}}
                <button id="applyBtn" class="btn btn-info" {{#if deadlinePassed}} disabled {{/if}}>Apply</button>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                Date of post {{ generateDate date 'MMMM DD YYYY'}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {{#pagination current=current pages=pages}}{{/pagination}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jesus, you're such a genius! Thank you it works!

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing?

Comment: Yes. But if it's big better open a new question and link it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603030/node-js-view-counter-without-registration-using-route